# how to draw the following diagram in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hi

I found this architecture in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06905.pdf) and I want to know if I can draw this in LaTex using tikZ

Comment: Hi on TeX ! Please show us what you do so far ! MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily,node distance=1ex,
    vector/.style={basic,minimum width=0em,inner
    ysep=1pt,font=\Huge,text height=1.25em,node contents={\foreach \XX in
    {1,...,#1}{\textbullet}}},vector/.default=5,
    basic/.style={draw,rounded corners,minimum width=8.5em},
    >=stealth,every edge/.append style={thick,->}] 
 \path[nodes=basic] foreach \X in {1,...,5} 
  {(\X,0) node(v\X)[rotate=90,vector]}
  node[above=2em of v3.east,fill=blue!20](BilSTM) {BilSTM}
  node[above=of BilSTM,fill=purple!20](CA) {Chunk Attention}
  node[above=of CA,fill=red!20](BN) {Batch Norm}
  node[above=2em of BN](v0)[vector=7,fill=gray!60,
    label={[align=center,font=\small,minimum width=0em]right:Document\\ Vector}]
  node[above=2em of v0,fill=green!20](D) {Defense}
  node[above=of D,fill=yellow!20](S) {Softmax}
  (v3.east) edge (BilSTM)  (BN) edge (v0) (v0) edge (D);
 \node[right=1em of v5.south,rotate=90,anchor=north,font=\small] {Chunk Embedding};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]